# Issue with itemEditor in AdvancedDataGrid when using hiearchical data as dataProvider

Tags: apache-flex, hierarchical-data, advanceddatagrid, itemeditor

Following is the sample code.

While I start editing either in optionId column or option column, the other rows of the same column are also get affected and reflecting the same value. But when I am editing in other columns it is working fine...
Don't know the reason. If anybody could help me.

```
 <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="electionGrid" width="100%" height="70%" folderOpenIcon="{null}" folderClosedIcon="{null}" defaultLeafIcon="{null}" editable="true">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:HierarchicalData source="{electionSummary}" childrenField="options"/>
        </mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="dbProduct" headerText="DB Product" editable="false"/>             
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="entitledQty" headerText="Entitled Quantity" editable="false"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="entityId" headerText="Entity Id" editable="false"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="entityName" headerText="Entity Name" editable="false"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="eventStatus" headerText="Event Status" editable="false"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="optionId" headerText="Option Id" itemEditor="mx.controls.TextInput" editorDataField="text"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="option" headerText="Description" itemEditor="mx.controls.TextInput" editorDataField="text"/>            
        </mx:columns>        
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Hiearchical Data :

```
 <mx:ArrayCollection id="optionData">
    <model:CAEventOption optionId="12345" option="Option1"/> 
    <model:CAEventOption optionId="56789" option="Option2"/>
    <model:CAEventOption optionId="89756" option="Option3"/>        
</mx:ArrayCollection>

<mx:ArrayCollection id="electionSummary">
    <model:ElectionStatusSummary dbProduct="Global PB" entitledQty="54500" entityId="DEM0001" entityName="Hedge Fund Long Short Period" 
                eventStatus="Awaiting Election" options="{new ArrayCollection(optionData.source)}"/>
    <model:ElectionStatusSummary dbProduct="Global PB" entitledQty="54500" entityId="DEM0001" entityName="Hedge Fund Long Short Period" 
                eventStatus="Awaiting Election" options="{new ArrayCollection(optionData.source)}"/>
    <model:ElectionStatusSummary dbProduct="Global PB" entitledQty="54500" entityId="DEM0001" entityName="Hedge Fund Long Short Period" 
                eventStatus="Awaiting Election" options="{new ArrayCollection(optionData.source)}"/>        
</mx:ArrayCollection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{new ArrayCollection(optionData.source)}` creates a new `ArrayCollection`. However, the underlying `Array` is always the same object (here `optionData`).

To prevent this from happening you'll have to create three different arrays containing different instances of `CAEventOption`. Something link this:

```
<mx:ArrayCollection id="electionSummary">
    <model:ElectionStatusSummary dbProduct="Global PB" entitledQty="54500" entityId="DEM0001"
                                 entityName="Hedge Fund Long Short Period" eventStatus="Awaiting Election">
        <model:options>
            <mx:ArrayCollection id="optionData">
                <model:CAEventOption optionId="12345" option="Option1"/>
                <model:CAEventOption optionId="56789" option="Option2"/>
                <model:CAEventOption optionId="89756" option="Option3"/>
            </mx:ArrayCollection>
        </model:options>
    </model:ElectionStatusSummary>
    <model:ElectionStatusSummary dbProduct="Global PB" entitledQty="54500" entityId="DEM0001"
                                 entityName="Hedge Fund Long Short Period" eventStatus="Awaiting Election">
        <model:options>
            <mx:ArrayCollection id="optionData">
                <model:CAEventOption optionId="12345" option="Option1"/>
                <model:CAEventOption optionId="56789" option="Option2"/>
                <model:CAEventOption optionId="89756" option="Option3"/>
            </mx:ArrayCollection>
        </model:options>
    </model:ElectionStatusSummary>
    <model:ElectionStatusSummary dbProduct="Global PB" entitledQty="54500" entityId="DEM0001"
                                 entityName="Hedge Fund Long Short Period" eventStatus="Awaiting Election">
        <model:options>
            <mx:ArrayCollection id="optionData">
                <model:CAEventOption optionId="12345" option="Option1"/>
                <model:CAEventOption optionId="56789" option="Option2"/>
                <model:CAEventOption optionId="89756" option="Option3"/>
            </mx:ArrayCollection>
        </model:options>
    </model:ElectionStatusSummary>
</mx:ArrayCollection>
```